# How can I start the TextToSpeech in application class and then use it in another activity in android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, text-to-speech

I am working on a Workout app that uses TextToSpeech in one of it's activity.  But the problem is TextToSpeech takes a very long time to start, so it completely misses one exercise and thereafter it works flawlessly. I tried to look for the solution on internet and found out that initialising the TextToSpeech in application class will load to the TextToSpeech on application startup and then it may work fine. The problem is I don't know how to initialise TextToSpeech in application class and then use it in the activity that I need it in. I searched the whole internet for this and found no solution. Please help me with this, I'm stuck.

Thank You!

Here is the code of the activity that I am using text to speech in

```
package khan.sajad.example.letsworkout

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import khan.sajad.example.letsworkout.data.Exercises
import khan.sajad.example.letsworkout.databinding.ActivityExerciseBinding
import java.util.*

class ExerciseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
   private lateinit var binding: ActivityExerciseBinding
   private var position = 0
   private var exerciseList = Exercises().loadExercises()

   // Text To speech variable
   private lateinit var textToSpeech: TextToSpeech

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       binding = ActivityExerciseBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       setContentView(binding.root)
       setSupportActionBar(binding.exerciseToolbar)
       // enables back button on toolbar
       supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
       // click-listener to the back button on the toolbar
       binding.exerciseToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
           position = 0
           onBackPressed()
           finish()
       }

       // Starting Text To Speech
       textToSpeech = TextToSpeech(this, this)

       startTimer()
   }

   private fun startTimer(){
       binding.tvTitle.text = getString(R.string.get_ready, exerciseList[position].name)

       // Speak out
       textToSpeech.speak(binding.tvTitle.text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "")
       
       object : CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
           override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
               binding.tvTimer.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString()
               binding.progressBar.progress = ((millisUntilFinished)/1000).toInt()
           }

           override fun onFinish() {

               setExerciseVisibility()
               startTimer30()
           }
       }.start()
   }

   private fun startTimer30(){
           val exercise = exerciseList[position]
           binding.tvTitle30.text = exercise.name
           showGif(exercise.image)
           object : CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
           override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
               binding.tvTimer30.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString()
               binding.progressBar30.progress = ((millisUntilFinished)/1000).toInt()
           }

           override fun onFinish() {
               position++
               if(position != exerciseList.size){
                   setBreakVisibility()
                   startTimer()
               }
               else{
                   setResultActivity()
               }
           }
       }.start()
   }

   private fun showGif(id: Int) {
       Glide.with(this).load(id).into(binding.ImageView30)
   }
   private fun setExerciseVisibility(){
       binding.frameLayout.visibility = View.GONE
       binding.tvTitle.visibility = View.GONE
       binding.frameLayout30.visibility = View.VISIBLE
       binding.tvTitle30.visibility = View.VISIBLE
       binding.ImageView30.visibility = View.VISIBLE
   }

   private fun setBreakVisibility(){
       binding.frameLayout30.visibility = View.GONE
       binding.tvTitle30.visibility = View.GONE
       binding.ImageView30.visibility = View.GONE
       binding.frameLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
       binding.tvTitle.visibility = View.VISIBLE
   }
   private fun setResultActivity(){
       val intent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
       startActivity(intent)
       finish()
   }


   // OnIt for text to speech
   override fun onInit(status: Int) {
       if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
           val langSet = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH)
           if(langSet == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || langSet == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
               Log.e("TTS", "Unable set the language!")
           }
       }
       else{
           Log.e("TTS", "Failed to start Text to speech")
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Inside your application onCreate()

val textToSpeech = TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this) 

and then implement onInit(status: Int) method.

also create a public function.

fun getTTSPlayer(){
    return textToSpeech;
}
```

Inside your activity call the getTTsPlayer using your application instance.